# Glue job writing Parquet Files to S3 with InCorrect Datatypes

Tags: aws-glue

I am using glue job. Glue job reads the input as manifest file which has JSON datafiles in it. After reading it to the dataframe we apply some kind of processing/trasnformations and then Glue job writes the data to a different S3 location in Parquet format. But the datatype of the parquet file columns is getting mapped to object and not string.

This is the code I tried:

```
df = df.withColumn("my_column", col("my_column").cast("string"))
And I am using below code to write it on s3
write_to_s3 = GLUE_CONTEXT.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=transformed_with_contracts,
        connection_type='s3',
        format='parquet',
        connection_options={
            'path': f's3://{destination_s3_bucket}/{destination_s3_path}'
        },
        format_options={},
        transformation_ctx='write_to_s3',
    )
```

Datatype of the parquet file columns is getting mapped to object and not string, which is not expected. Any ideas?

Comment: this seems to be working for me on a test dataset, how are you creating a dataframe? you can also try  final_df.printSchema() and then cast it as per your use-case

Comment: When I read the generated parquet file using pandan locally I can see that string is mapped to Object type
datafram = pd.read_parquet('k.snappy.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
print(datafram.dtypes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comments I can conclude that the issue is not with the Glue job, it is writing the parquet files as expected

In Pandas, since strings data types have variable length, it is by default stored as object dtype. Please see the below workaround

Tested it with awswrangler module, which treats the column as string rather than object.

```
import awswrangler as wr
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path="s3://<bucket>/<path>/<file>.parquet")
df.to_parquet("s3://<bucket>/path>/<file>.parquet")
df.info()
```

Try using this instead!